# NSUserDefaults not saving StandardUserDefaults values

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, nsuserdefaults

I have an iOS application developed using Microsoft's Xamarin, which is why some of this code might look different. In any case, here is what I'm trying to do:

In my application, I have a set of default user settings that need to be in every single instance of the application no matter what. This is set using this method:

```
    public static void SetDefaults()
    {
        var keys = new object[]
        {
            "LastNotificationTime",
            "LastSyncTime",
            "LunchStartTime",
            "LunchEndTime",
            "OnLunchBreak",
            "PunchedIn",
            "PunchTime",
            "ShowDetailPane",
            "NotifyEmergency",
            "RunAtBoot",
            "RowsPerPage",
            "SyncInterval"
        };
        var values = new object[]
        {
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            false,
            false,
            "",
            true,
            true,
            false,
            5,
            60
        };
        var defaults = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(defaults);
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
    }
```

This works great *during* the initial run of my application. I will deploy on my device from scratch, run the application, and then stop. I will then redeploy the already-installed application. I don't want to wipe out the defaults and set truly-default values every time, so I perform this check before doing so (in this example, `Settings.GetPreferences()` returns the `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults` object):

```
    if( Settings.GetPreferences().IntForKey("RowsPerPage") == 0 || 
        Settings.GetPreferences().IntForKey("RowsPerPage") == null )
    {
        Settings.SetDefaults();
    }
```

As you can see above, RowsPerPage is initially set to 5. I am expecting this value, for each run after the subsequent initial installation, to persist as being 5. Or whatever the user chooses, for that matter.

However, the above check always comes out as true, and my `SetDefaults()` method is called, wiping out any changes the user made to their Defaults during the last run. Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong when setting these defaults? Even after adding the not-recommended, deprecated `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize()` method call, the defaults are still reset.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the user default for that key is actually 0 or null? Not sure from your code how the `IntForKey` is implemented or whether the `FromObjectsAndKeys` properly handles `Int` values.

Note also the `registerDefaults` function should not overwrite/wipe out existing defaults, it just registers them the first time. You do not really need to call it for anything other than keys that you don't want to have a default value (e.g. false for boolean, null for others etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `RegisterDefaults` doesn't do what you think it does:

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1417065-registerdefaults?language=objc)

> The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts.

If you want to establish initial values for your defaults that persist then you will need an individual `set` operation for each one in your `SetDefaults` method, rather than using `RegisterDefaults`

Comment: Bingo. I had a feeling that this was the case and I was actually going to try doing it this morning. Thanks for the reply and thanks for confirming my thought. +1!